# How can I get the deviceId of my Android emulator?

Tags: android, emulation

I am developing an android app which can able to get push notifications. But I need to have a deviceId to make it successful and as I don't have any android phone, I used to test the app in emulator. So my question is, can I get a deviceId for my emulator.

Comment: do you mean ANDROID_ID?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402262/device-identifier-of-android-emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't get device id in android but you can get IMEI number for push notification. bcoz all  devices has different IMEI number. In Emulator you get by default 0000000000000 As your IMEI but in device you get perfect number. below is the code to get IMEI number

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager1 = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String imei = telephonyManager1.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: ask me if you have further any query

Comment: but consider that tablet with no mobile data connection do not have an IMEI

Answer (score 4):

The command 'adb devices' also lists the active emulators, which can give the device id.

Answer (score 2):

Through the Android emulators:

1. Click the "More" dots at the bottom of the side menu.
2. Go to "Help" section at bottom of navigation panel on the left.
3. Inside "Help" go to the "About" Tab.
4. Here you will find the serial number. Which in some cases is called the "deviceId".

Answer (score 1):

Use this method, this  **works for Tablet and Phone** both

```
   public  String getDeviceID(Context context) {
                TelephonyManager manager = 
                    (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                String deviceId;
                if (manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE) {
                    //Tablet
                     deviceId = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                            Secure.ANDROID_ID);

                } else {
                    //Mobile
                     deviceId = manager.getDeviceId();

                }
                return deviceId;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
public static String getIMEI() {
    String IMEI = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    return IMEI;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the **device Id** of your emulator >>>

Inside **onCreate()** method add this two line :

```
 String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
String deviceId = md5(android_id).toUpperCase();
Log.i("device id=",deviceId);
```

*outside* the onCreate() method add this **md5()** method :

```
public String md5(String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

To find the device id just **run the app and open the logcat** in your android studio and tap in the search bar " device id "
[image]