# Can an emulator have a unique device ID? And can you use that ID?

Tags: android, cordova, emulation, uuid

I am making a web app using HTML5 and PhoneGap, and I am using the uuid as a one-time login instead of the standard username/password combination.
Instead of having the client manually type in the uuid, I want to automatically grab the uuid from the device and login using that information.
There is a PhoneGap plugin called Device, which allows you to access your device's uuid.

When I try to test the uuid retrieval on Genymotion, my emulator, I get an error.
I think the error is because I am using an emulator and not a device.

EDIT: I found the identifiers on Genymotion, but it is not free. I am still wondering whether I can actually use the ID information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set uuid for a emulator.

You need to start the emulator like this

```
emulator -avd jbx86 -prop emu.uuid=5ec33f90-a471-11e2-9e96-0800200c9a66
```

Basically emulator uuID always returns null. They are hard coded. So you can set at startup.

Answers are taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402262/device-identifier-of-android-emulator)

See [this](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/starting-and-stopping-android-emulators/) for more example, in the 'Detecting correct emulator' section.

Comment: Can you explain that format? I tried it and it didn't know what "jbx86" was.

Comment: I didn't try them, I've found them from those above links. There is another way described in the 2nd link, you can try them

Comment: Should this solution still work? Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here "jbx86" is the AVD name that you may have used during emulator creation under "Android Virtual Device Manager"